# Moving an object on imageview on zoom in and zoom out

Tags: android, image, imageview, zooming

There is a draggable object over the imageview which has been set as background in android. When the background imageview zooms, I want the object to stay in the same position as it was before.for example, if it was over a text called "smile" in that image then, it should stay there even after zooming.

I want the image works just like google maps when we add marker to a map the marker moves according to zoom in and out.

Comment: yes through setImageMatrix()

Comment: yes also the image will be on the same place. just like google map marker.

Comment: i just want the object remain on the same place on Imageview when zoom in or out or scroll the zoomed imaged. Object scaled or not is not an issue, if object can't be scaled be scaled than no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below class of Framlayout for that, It will zoom all the content inside that.

```
public class ZoomableLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public ZoomableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ZoomableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ZoomableLayout(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Zooming view listener interface.
     *
     * @author karooolek
     *
     */
    public interface ZoomViewListener {

        void onZoomStarted(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);

        void onZooming(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);

        void onZoomEnded(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);
    }

    // zooming
    float zoom = 1.0f;
    float maxZoom = 2.0f;
    float smoothZoom = 1.0f;
    float zoomX, zoomY;
    float smoothZoomX, smoothZoomY;
    private boolean scrolling; //

    // minimap variables
    private boolean showMinimap = false;
    private int miniMapColor = Color.WHITE;
    private int miniMapHeight = -1;
    private String miniMapCaption;
    private float miniMapCaptionSize = 10.0f;
    private int miniMapCaptionColor = Color.WHITE;

    // touching variables
    private long lastTapTime;
    private float touchStartX, touchStartY;
    private float touchLastX, touchLastY;
    private float startd;
    private boolean pinching;
    private float lastd;
    private float lastdx1, lastdy1;
    private float lastdx2, lastdy2;

    // drawing
    private final Matrix m = new Matrix();
    private final Paint p = new Paint();

    // listener
    ZoomViewListener listener;

    private Bitmap ch;

    public float getZoom() {
        return zoom;
    }

    public float getMaxZoom() {
        return maxZoom;
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(final float maxZoom) {
        if (maxZoom < 1.0f) {
            return;
        }

        this.maxZoom = maxZoom;
    }

    public void setMiniMapEnabled(final boolean showMiniMap) {
        this.showMinimap = showMiniMap;
    }

    public boolean isMiniMapEnabled() {
        return showMinimap;
    }

    public void setMiniMapHeight(final int miniMapHeight) {
        if (miniMapHeight < 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.miniMapHeight = miniMapHeight;
    }

    public int getMiniMapHeight() {
        return miniMapHeight;
    }

    public void setMiniMapColor(final int color) {
        miniMapColor = color;
    }

    public int getMiniMapColor() {
        return miniMapColor;
    }

    public String getMiniMapCaption() {
        return miniMapCaption;
    }

    public void setMiniMapCaption(final String miniMapCaption) {
        this.miniMapCaption = miniMapCaption;
    }

    public float getMiniMapCaptionSize() {
        return miniMapCaptionSize;
    }

    public void setMiniMapCaptionSize(final float size) {
        miniMapCaptionSize = size;
    }

    public int getMiniMapCaptionColor() {
        return miniMapCaptionColor;
    }

    public void setMiniMapCaptionColor(final int color) {
        miniMapCaptionColor = color;
    }

    public void zoomTo(final float zoom, final float x, final float y) {
        this.zoom = Math.min(zoom, maxZoom);
        zoomX = x;
        zoomY = y;
        smoothZoomTo(this.zoom, x, y);
    }

    public void smoothZoomTo(final float zoom, final float x, final float y) {
        smoothZoom = clamp(1.0f, zoom, maxZoom);
        smoothZoomX = x;
        smoothZoomY = y;
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onZoomStarted(smoothZoom, x, y);
        }
    }

    public ZoomViewListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public void setListner(final ZoomViewListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public float getZoomFocusX() {
        return zoomX * zoom;
    }

    public float getZoomFocusY() {
        return zoomY * zoom;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        // single touch
        if (ev.getPointerCount() == 1) {
            processSingleTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        // // double touch
        if (ev.getPointerCount() == 2) {
            processDoubleTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        // redraw
        getRootView().invalidate();
        invalidate();

        return true;
    }

    private void processSingleTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {

        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
        final float h = miniMapHeight;
        final boolean touchingMiniMap = x >= 10.0f && x <= 10.0f + w
                && y >= 10.0f && y <= 10.0f + h;

        if (showMinimap && smoothZoom > 1.0f && touchingMiniMap) {
            processSingleTouchOnMinimap(ev);
        } else {
            processSingleTouchOutsideMinimap(ev);
        }
    }

    private void processSingleTouchOnMinimap(final MotionEvent ev) {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
        final float h = miniMapHeight;
        final float zx = (x - 10.0f) / w * getWidth();
        final float zy = (y - 10.0f) / h * getHeight();
        smoothZoomTo(smoothZoom, zx, zy);
    }

    private void processSingleTouchOutsideMinimap(final MotionEvent ev) {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();
        float lx = x - touchStartX;
        float ly = y - touchStartY;
        final float l = (float) Math.hypot(lx, ly);
        float dx = x - touchLastX;
        float dy = y - touchLastY;
        touchLastX = x;
        touchLastY = y;

        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStartX = x;
                touchStartY = y;
                touchLastX = x;
                touchLastY = y;
                dx = 0;
                dy = 0;
                lx = 0;
                ly = 0;
                scrolling = false;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (scrolling || (smoothZoom > 1.0f && l > 30.0f)) {
                    if (!scrolling) {
                        scrolling = true;
                        ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                    }
                    smoothZoomX -= dx / zoom;
                    smoothZoomY -= dy / zoom;
                    return;
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                // tap
                if (l < 30.0f) {
                    // check double tap
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTapTime < 500) {
                        if (smoothZoom == 1.0f) {
                            smoothZoomTo(maxZoom, x, y);
                        } else {
                            smoothZoomTo(1.0f, getWidth() / 2.0f,
                                    getHeight() / 2.0f);
                        }
                        lastTapTime = 0;
                        ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                        return;
                    }

                    lastTapTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    performClick();
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        ev.setLocation(zoomX + (x - 0.5f * getWidth()) / zoom, zoomY
                + (y - 0.5f * getHeight()) / zoom);

        ev.getX();
        ev.getY();

        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private void processDoubleTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        final float x1 = ev.getX(0);
        final float dx1 = x1 - lastdx1;
        lastdx1 = x1;
        final float y1 = ev.getY(0);
        final float dy1 = y1 - lastdy1;
        lastdy1 = y1;
        final float x2 = ev.getX(1);
        final float dx2 = x2 - lastdx2;
        lastdx2 = x2;
        final float y2 = ev.getY(1);
        final float dy2 = y2 - lastdy2;
        lastdy2 = y2;

        // pointers distance
        final float d = (float) Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        final float dd = d - lastd;
        lastd = d;
        final float ld = Math.abs(d - startd);

        Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startd = d;
                pinching = false;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (pinching || ld > 30.0f) {
                    pinching = true;
                    final float dxk = 0.5f * (dx1 + dx2);
                    final float dyk = 0.5f * (dy1 + dy2);
                    smoothZoomTo(Math.max(1.0f, zoom * d / (d - dd)), zoomX - dxk
                            / zoom, zoomY - dyk / zoom);
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            default:
                pinching = false;
                break;
        }

        ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private float clamp(final float min, final float value, final float max) {
        return Math.max(min, Math.min(value, max));
    }

    private float lerp(final float a, final float b, final float k) {
        return a + (b - a) * k;
    }

    private float bias(final float a, final float b, final float k) {
        return Math.abs(b - a) >= k ? a + k * Math.signum(b - a) : b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas) {

        // do zoom
        zoom = lerp(bias(zoom, smoothZoom, 0.05f), smoothZoom, 0.2f);
        smoothZoomX = clamp(0.5f * getWidth() / smoothZoom, smoothZoomX,
                getWidth() - 0.5f * getWidth() / smoothZoom);
        smoothZoomY = clamp(0.5f * getHeight() / smoothZoom, smoothZoomY,
                getHeight() - 0.5f * getHeight() / smoothZoom);

        zoomX = lerp(bias(zoomX, smoothZoomX, 0.1f), smoothZoomX, 0.35f);
        zoomY = lerp(bias(zoomY, smoothZoomY, 0.1f), smoothZoomY, 0.35f);
        if (zoom != smoothZoom && listener != null) {
            listener.onZooming(zoom, zoomX, zoomY);
        }

        final boolean animating = Math.abs(zoom - smoothZoom) > 0.0000001f
                || Math.abs(zoomX - smoothZoomX) > 0.0000001f
                || Math.abs(zoomY - smoothZoomY) > 0.0000001f;

        // nothing to draw
        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // prepare matrix
        m.setTranslate(0.5f * getWidth(), 0.5f * getHeight());
        m.preScale(zoom, zoom);
        m.preTranslate(
                -clamp(0.5f * getWidth() / zoom, zoomX, getWidth() - 0.5f
                        * getWidth() / zoom),
                -clamp(0.5f * getHeight() / zoom, zoomY, getHeight() - 0.5f
                        * getHeight() / zoom));

        // get view
        final View v = getChildAt(0);
        m.preTranslate(v.getLeft(), v.getTop());

        // get drawing cache if available
        if (animating && ch == null && isAnimationCacheEnabled()) {
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            ch = v.getDrawingCache();
        }

        // draw using cache while animating
        if (animating && isAnimationCacheEnabled() && ch != null) {
            p.setColor(0xffffffff);
            canvas.drawBitmap(ch, m, p);
        } else { // zoomed or cache unavailable
            ch = null;
            canvas.save();
            canvas.concat(m);
            v.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }

        // draw minimap
        if (showMinimap) {
            if (miniMapHeight < 0) {
                miniMapHeight = getHeight() / 4;
            }

            canvas.translate(10.0f, 10.0f);

            p.setColor(0x80000000 | 0x00ffffff & miniMapColor);
            final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
            final float h = miniMapHeight;
            canvas.drawRect(0.0f, 0.0f, w, h, p);

            if (miniMapCaption != null && miniMapCaption.length() > 0) {
                p.setTextSize(miniMapCaptionSize);
                p.setColor(miniMapCaptionColor);
                p.setAntiAlias(true);
                canvas.drawText(miniMapCaption, 10.0f,
                        10.0f + miniMapCaptionSize, p);
                p.setAntiAlias(false);
            }

            p.setColor(0x80000000 | 0x00ffffff & miniMapColor);
            final float dx = w * zoomX / getWidth();
            final float dy = h * zoomY / getHeight();
            canvas.drawRect(dx - 0.5f * w / zoom, dy - 0.5f * h / zoom, dx
                    + 0.5f * w / zoom, dy + 0.5f * h / zoom, p);

            canvas.translate(-10.0f, -10.0f);
        }

        // redraw
        // if (animating) {
        getRootView().invalidate();
        invalidate();
        // }
    }
}
```

Add this to your xml as below,

```
<com.example.myapplication.Activities.Utils.ZoomableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/zoom_layout"
        >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                // Your contents here
            </RelativeLayout>

    </com.example.myapplication.Activities.Utils.ZoomableLayout>
```